# Trying to create email log system but array stays blank

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

So I'm trying to create some sort of email log system with the subject and message previewed on each line, like gmail.

In `mainWindowScript.py`, I have a 'compose' button that appends a string to an array in `getLogs.py`, and a 'logs' button that runs `getLogs.py` using the os module. In `getLogs.py`, I just have a `ListBox`. I used tkinter to create buttons and `listboxes`.

When I run `mainWindowScript.py`, it first opens the `listbox` created in `getLogs.py` which isn't supposed to happen. But the weird part is when I close that window and click my 'compose' button, the list I tried to append to is still empty, making the `listbox` empty.

It's really confusing I need help.

Here is `mainWindowScript.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os

import getLogs as gl

mainWin = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(mainWin, width = 400, height = 400)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(mainWin, bg = "gray")
frame.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)


def compose():
    gl.tos.append("isybgf")
    #os.system("python email_gui.py")            #run another python file


def getEmailLogs():
    os.system("python getLogs.py")


composeButton = tk.Button(frame, bg = "blue", fg = "white", text = "COMPOSE", command = compose)
composeButton.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.2, relwidth = 0.4, relheight = 0.2)

logsButton = tk.Button(frame, bg = "blue", fg = "white", text = "LOGS", command = getEmailLogs)
logsButton.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.5, relwidth = 0.4, relheight = 0.2)

mainWin.mainloop()
```

And `getLogs.py`:

```
import tkinter as tk

mainWind = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(mainWind, width = 400, height = 600)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(mainWind, bg = "gray")
frame.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

mailLogs = tk.Listbox(frame)
mailLogs.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.05, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.9)

tos = []
subjects = []
messages = []

print(tos)

mails = {
    "to:": tos,
    "subject:": subjects,
    "message:": messages
}

for i in range(0, len(tos)):
    emailLogTitle = "{}: {} - {}".format(mails["to:"][i], mails["subject:"][i], mails["message:"][i])
    mailLogs.insert('end', emailLogTitle)

mainWind.mainloop()
```

Comment: put code in fuctions and run functions after import it.  Using `os.system("python getLogs.py")` you run separated program which know nothing about list `tos` which you created in `mainWindowScript` - it starts with own empty list `tos` and has no access to data create in `mainWindowScript.py`.

Comment: BTW: when you import `import getLogs as gl` then you automatically run code from `getLogs.py` so you see it at start. If you put code in function(s) then it will not run it at start and you may run it as `gl.function()` when you press button - without using `os.system()`

Comment: if you want to run it as `os.system("python getLogs.py")` then you would have to save data from `tos` in file and `getLogs.py` would have to read these data from file.

Comment: Read up on [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules), [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Answer (score 0):

Using `os.system()` you run separated program which has no access to data create in current program. Because you import `getLogs` so you should put code in function to execute it without `os.system()`

`getLogs.py`

```
import tkinter as tk

tos = []
subjects = []
messages = []

def log_window():

    #mainWind = tk.Tk()
    mainWind = tk.Toplevel()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(mainWind, width = 400, height = 600)
    canvas.pack()

    frame = tk.Frame(mainWind, bg = "gray")
    frame.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

    mailLogs = tk.Listbox(frame)
    mailLogs.place(relx = 0.1, rely = 0.05, relwidth = 0.8, relheight = 0.9)

    print(tos)

    mails = {
        "to:": tos,
        "subject:": subjects,
        "message:": messages
    }

    for i in range(0, len(tos)):
        emailLogTitle = "{}: {} - {}".format(mails["to:"][i], mails["subject:"][i], mails["message:"][i])
        mailLogs.insert('end', emailLogTitle)

    #mainWind.mainloop()
```

And now you can execute it

```
def getEmailLogs():
    gl.log_window()
```

and it will have access to values in `tos`

---

Because both windows run in the same program so second doesn't need `mainloop()` and it should be created by `Toplevel()`, not `Tk()`

---

BTW: composer was adding only `tos` so later dictionary `mail` was no subjects and messages. You could rather create one list with mails instead of separated list for `to`,  `subject`, `message`

---

mai.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

import getLogs as gl

# --- functions ---

def compose():
    gl.tos.append("isybgf")
    gl.subjects.append("isybgf")
    gl.messages.append("isybgf")
    # it could be better to keep it in one list ie.
    # mails.append( {'to': "isybgf", 'subject': "isybgf", 'message': "isybgf" } )

def getEmailLogs():
    gl.log_window()

# --- main ---

mainWin = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(mainWin, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(mainWin, bg="gray")
frame.place(relx = 0, rely = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

composeButton = tk.Button(frame, bg="blue", fg="white", text="COMPOSE", command=compose)
composeButton.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.2)

logsButton = tk.Button(frame, bg="blue", fg="white", text="LOGS", command=getEmailLogs)
logsButton.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.2)

mainWin.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Version with other changes - reduced to important elements. I keep mails on one list `mails` in main program and send to log as argument.

main.py

```
import tkinter as tk
import getLogs as gl

# --- functions ---

def compose():
    mails.append( {'to': "user@domain.com", 'subject': "Read it", 'message': "Hello World!"} )

def get_email_logs():
    gl.log_window(mails)

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

mails = []

main_window = tk.Tk()

compose_button = tk.Button(main_window, text="COMPOSE", command=compose)
compose_button.pack(fill='x')

logs_button = tk.Button(main_window, text="LOGS", command=get_email_logs)
logs_button.pack(fill='x')

close_button = tk.Button(main_window, text="CLOSE", command=main_window.destroy)
close_button.pack(fill='x')

main_window.mainloop()
```

getLogs.py

```
import tkinter as tk

def log_window(mails):

    window = tk.Toplevel()

    mail_logs = tk.Listbox(window)
    mail_logs.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    close_button = tk.Button(window, text="CLOSE", command=window.destroy)
    close_button.pack(fill='x')

    for item in mails:
        mail_logs.insert('end', "{}: {} - {}".format( item["to"], item["subject"], item["message"] ))
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who gave a solution! It really helped.